# MySQL Operand should contain 1 column - how to overcome

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following MySQL code:

```
SELECT company, ((AVG (q1) + AVG(q2) + AVG(q3) ) / 3) AS High,
(SELECT company, ((AVG (q1) + AVG(q2) + AVG(q3) ) / 3) 
FROM tresults_new GROUP BY company ASC LIMIT 1) AS Low
FROM tresults_new GROUP BY company DESC LIMIT 1
```

Now I understand why this brings back the error in the title, as I am bringing back both `company` and `Low` in the subquery.

What I am struggling with is `how` to return both the `High` and `Low` (or if you prefer `Max` and `Min`) in a single query and I cannot fathom if it is possible and how I would go about it.

Any and all suggestions and feedback welcomed.

**For reference, table structure**:

```
company    q1     q2     q3
abc        5      6      2
abc        9      5      8
xyz        3      4      6
xyz        3      2      1
zyx        7      9      10
```

Comment: are you trying to get the max and min values from the query you have?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Hence the sentence about how to return both the High and Low.  Thanks.

Comment: @Homer_J Sorry I don't understand _high_ and _low_ in this context and struggle to infer what you're looking for from your query. Could you please post a sample of your `tresults_new` table and the desired query output?

Comment: @Homer_J If you're looking for the min/max, why do you have averages over `q[1,2,3]`?

Comment: I need the Max and Min averages based on company.  Updated table again.

Comment: If we're grouping on `company` to compute the averages, then there's only one average (value) for each of `q1`, `q2` and `q3` per company. If we're on the same page so far, then I fail to see what you mean by _Max and Min averages based on company_. Could give the sample output for the values above?

Comment: Thanks for the reply - image I have 20 companies, I need an average for Q1, Q2, Q3 for each company and then I need to know which company has the highest(max) and the lowest(min) - so I need just two numbers.  I can easily achieve this with two separate queries - what I was wondering was if it were possible to achieve this within one.

Comment: i have to say that @okiharaherbst has a point. if you're getting the average for all q1, q2 and q3 then you're only getting 1 value per company. so it's confusing what data you are actually trying to get out of this dataset. i think a sample output would be helpful because i'm not sure your explanation is clear enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the max and min functions should help. I tend to work in SQL Server but this should be true for MySQL as well.

**UPDATED AFTER FURTHER CLARIFICATION**

So after all the comments on both my response. OPs post and another response. I fiddled around a bit and this should actually get you what you want. It's possibly overblown if you are only doing this once but if your data set grows large this should accomplish what you need and still give you the max and min values that you desire so you know your highest and lowest performing companies. I also did a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f7259/11) if you want to play with it yourself - to be clear I used SQL Server because I'm more familiar in the fiddle example but any changes to MySQL should be relatively trivial.

```
SELECT vals.company, vals.myval
FROM
(SELECT company, ((AVG (q1) + AVG(q2) + AVG(q3) ) / 3) as myval
     FROM tresults_new GROUP BY company
) vals
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT max(myval) val
  FROM 
    (SELECT company, ((AVG (q1) + AVG(q2) + AVG(q3) ) / 3) as myval
     FROM tresults_new GROUP BY company
    ) s
  UNION
  SELECT min(myval) val
  FROM 
    (SELECT company, ((AVG (q1) + AVG(q2) + AVG(q3) ) / 3) as myval
     FROM tresults_new GROUP BY company
    ) s
) maxmin on maxmin.val = vals.myval
```

Comment: Thanks @rhealitycheck - does that bring back both the max and min in one query?

Comment: oh ooops i forgot to add the min the first time. but yes now it should do both in the same query.

Comment: hmmm here you're grouping on `company` twice, but the max and min will irrevocably be the same.

Comment: @okiharaherbst any time you use an aggregate function you need to group. so in the inner query there needs to be a grouping in order to calculate the avg functions. in the second piece you need to group by company to get the max and min functions to calculate as well.

Comment: @rhealitycheck I know. But look, due to the grouping in your inner query, just one row with the tuple `(company, myval)` for each company will be returned, do you agree with me? Therefore, the `min(myval)`, `max(myval)` in your outer query will be the same for each company because you're grouping again on company. There's just one row, therefore just one `myval` to choose from. Understand?

Comment: @okiharaherbst actually yes i see what you're saying. i got sidetracked thinking that OP just wanted max and min and didn't consider that the averages would end up returning only one row per company.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can reasonably avoid two queries or it would be a subquery which leaves you no better off. From your comment and your sample query, I understand that you're just interested in which company has the highest value of `AVG(q1)+AVG(q2)+AVG(q3)` and which other has the lowest value thereof. In this case I'd just rely on a single query ordered by this value. The first and last rows will be your answer.

```
SELECT company, val FROM
    (SELECT company, AVG(q1) + AVG(q2) + AVG(q3) AS val
    FROM tresults_new 
    GROUP BY company
    ORDER BY val DESC LIMIT 1) 
AS VAL_MAX

UNION

SELECT company, val FROM
    (SELECT company, AVG(q1) + AVG(q2) + AVG(q3) AS val
    FROM tresults_new 
    GROUP BY company
    ORDER BY val ASC LIMIT 1)
AS VAL_MIN
```

or just one query without `LIMIT` clause and get the first and last rows.

---

**Warning**: Of course, it would be tempting to write something like:

```
SELECT company, MIN(val), MAX(val) FROM 
    (SELECT company, AVG(q1) + AVG(q2) + AVG(q3) AS val
    FROM tresults_new 
    GROUP BY company)
AS values [GROUP BY company]
```

**without** the last `GROUP BY company`, you'll get the min the max but not the company (this query would be accepted by MySQL but rejected by a number of other RDBMS because you need explicit grouping).

So add the `GROUP BY` and you'll just get the same values for both min and max which leaves you no better off than your inner query.

Comment: Cheers, appreciate the feedback - I'm getting an `Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY` when using the above however.

Comment: you can't use order by in the first query when you use union

Comment: Yup, just spotted that!

Comment: @Homer_J That's why I'd just stick with just the inner query without the `LIMIT` clause and lookup the first and last values (if your result set is not too long).